# Do we need both tags, "babysitter" and "babysit"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 18 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitter) tagged [babysitter](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitter).

We currently have 4 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysit) tagged [babysit](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysit).

(One [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/2402/30519) is tagged [babysitter](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitter) and [babysit](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysit)).

Both tags have no tag wiki.

There seems to be a large overlap in meaning, so I wonder if it is really necessary to differentiate between them?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to keep only one tag for everything about babysitting - whether it's from a babysitter's point of view, about influence of babysitting or comparison to, for example, childcare etc.

This would make it easier to search for such questions and so enhances the user experience, without losing important meaning.

However, I believe we should neither keep *babysitter* nor *babysit* and choose instead:

[babysitting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitting)

It covers the whole spectrum of meaning and is in accordance with other verb-based tags (eating, teaching, feeding, breast-feeding, homeschooling etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think we should keep them separately.

One - Babysitter - should be questions about having a babysitter/finding a babysitter/interacting with a babysitter.  (I.e., it's questions a parent would ask.)

Two - Babysitting, perhaps is better for this - should be for questions about the act of babysitting, for example about how to become a babysitter, how to be a good babysitter, how to approach certain things as a babysitter (such as discipline issues).  (These are on-topic here, at least in my opinion, despite not being questions a parent would ask.  If that's controversial I'm happy to discuss why separately.)  These are questions a babysitter would ask.

These are totally different sets of questions, and so deserve different tags.  Looking through [babysitter](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitter), it looks like there are a few questions for the latter, and mostly for the former.

Comment: I understand you, but 3 things to consider: 1) it's not new to have one tag for totally different sets of questions (*parents* -> between parents, from a child's perspective), 2) it's not intuitive (why is *babysitter* only from the parent's perspective, but *babysitting* from the babysitter's perspective), 3) We do not have that many questions (since one had both tags, 21 questions overall) so should we split them up further? What do you think about that? Most important to me seems to me point 2, since it may seem confusing to users.

Comment: I now changed *babysit* to *babysitting* and also updated the *babysitter* questions asked from a babysitter's point of view. Please note that 2 out of 4 *babysit(ing)* questions are from the parents' point of view and would have to be changed again. Overall, there are 15 "parents" questions (2 are a bit unclear, though) and 6 "babysitter" questions. Not only a rather low number for having its own tag, the confusion always persisted and to me, babysitting and babysitter are too close to denote two separate issues. For filtering questions, having two distinct tags may actually be harmful.