# [Childcare], [Daycare], do we even care?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have currently two tags seemingly referring to the very same thing:

[daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare)
Currently 78 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare)
Usage guidance:

> Social interactions, subject matter addressed, safety at daycare centers, choosing a daycare center, staff behavior, and other issues related to daycare centers.

[childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare)
Currently 33 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare)
No usage guidance

I quote the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_care) entry on childcare

> Child care, or otherwise known as daycare, is the care and supervision of a child or multiple children at a time, whose ages range from six weeks to thirteen years. Child care is the action or skill of looking after children by a day-care center, nannies, babysitter, teachers or other providers. Child care is a broad topic that covers a wide spectrum of professionals, institutions, contexts, activities, and social and cultural conventions.

Most of these are already covered by existing other tags:
- [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare) for daycare centers, kindergarden etc.
- [babysitting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitting) for babysitters (also use it for nannies or child minders?)
- [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) / [teacher](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teacher) for everything school-related

Does this leave any use for a specific [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) tag?

Glancing at the questions taggged [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare), it's noticeable that [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) is used for questions about

- <strike>babysitters</strike> -> [babysitting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitting)

<strike>[1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/35143/30519), [2](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/20598/30519) (child minder), [3](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/16545/30519) (babysitter vs child minder), [4](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11888/30519) (nanny cam), [5](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/11749/30519) (nanny), [6](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/8766/30519) (nanny share), [7](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/2012/30519) (nanny)</strike>

- <strike>daycare / kindergarden</strike> -> [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare)

<strike>[1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34607/30519) (yes, added by me when I was still young and foolish), [2](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27613/30519), [3](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27732/30519), [4](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29601/30519), [5](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/26865/30519), [6](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/9189/30519), [7](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/6198/30519), [8](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/4405/30519), [9](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/3624/30519)</strike>

- <strike>"I care about my child", hence "childcare"</strike>

<strike>[1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/35182/30519), [2](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34268/30519), [3](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/32383/30519), [4](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29685/30519), [5](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/26901/30519) (or maybe babysitter), [6](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24469/30519), [7](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24416/30519), [8](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22128/30519), [9](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22111/30519), [10](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/21940/30519), [11](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/18328/30519), [12](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/17993/30519), [13](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/16782/30519), [14](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/14947/30519), [15](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/14417/30519), [16](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/8101/30519), [17](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/7136/30519)</strike>

When it's used as a synonym of daycare, it provides much better UX for them to all to be tagged [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare), so questions can be filtered accordingly.

The "I care about my child" usage seems unnecessary. People who don't care about their children would else probably not ask here. Its usage reminds me of [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) or [child](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child). It can be removed.

And then there are cases when it's used as a synonym of "babysitter". An interesting question is whether [babysitting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babysitting) should also encompass "child minder" and "nanny"? If not, I'd rather suggest specific tags for those, and not a tag like [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) that could mean everything.

**What's your opinion on these tags?**

Comment: I'm with you. Daycare in my mind is an institution with employees. Childcare can be done by grandmothers, nannies, friends groups. A nanny falls under child care, and they are all *in loco parentis.* Maybe babysitter questions should come from those who want to babysit?

Comment: @anongoodnurse We discussed [babysitting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1287/30519) already separately and the community was in favor of having [babysitting] for babysitters and parents.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had forgotten that!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest we use [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare) for institutions with employees, like kindergardens. It has been used to tag such questions much more often and is more clear.

In principle, [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) might be a useful tag, but it turned out not to be, in my opinion. Instead, it became some kind of a wastebasket tag with most questions not related to daycare or even babysitting. This defeats the purpose of a tag, which is to allow filtering questions. E. g. if you want to know how to deal with your 9-year-old, search for [middle-childhood](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-childhood) and you won't have to wade through questions about breastfeeding newborns, for example.

If you want advice on something daycare-related, you should be able to conveniently use [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare). But now, you'll not only find not all of them, since some are tagged [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare), searching for [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) will also lead to many unrelated questions (23 out of 33).

Since [childcare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/childcare) is misused so often, I do not even believe it should become [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare)'s *tag synonym*. This would just necessitate further editing of new questions tagged [daycare](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daycare), when they are not about daycare.